# I am trying to make a system model for sales and it does not save the sales in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel to make a system model in the view, I am showing the products with the price and adding them to another table where the subtotal and the total of the sale are calculated, I am also registering clients which verifies if the client already exists through of the ci, if the sale already exists, it is assigned to that customer and if it does not exist, a new customer is created

this is the view I'm using:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Añadir venta')
@section('plugins.Select2', true)

@section('content')
\<div class="container"\>
\<div class="row"\>
\<div class="col-md-6"\>
\<div class="card"\>
@if ($promociones-\>count() \> 0)
@foreach ($promociones as $promocion)
\<div class="alert alert-success d-flex align-items-center marquesina"\>
<img src="{{ asset(">
\<div\>

<h4>Promoción {{$promocion-\>nombre}} Especial</h4>
<p>{{ 'Por la compra de ' . $promocion-\>descripcion }}</p>
<p>{{'Recibe un descuento del '. $promocion-\>precio_venta}}</p>
\
\
@endforeach
@endif
\

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Productos:</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('ventas.store') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar productos"><br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped" id="productos-table">
                                        <thead style="background-color: #6777ef">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="color:#fff;">Imagen</th>
                                                <th style="color:#fff;">Nombre</th>
                                                <th style="color:#fff;">Cantidad</th>
                                                <th style="color:#fff;">Precio</th>
                                                <th style="color:#fff;">Acción</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><img src="{{ asset('imagenes/' . $producto->imagen) }}" alt="Imagen de producto" width="50"></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input disabled value="{{ $producto->IDproductos }}" name="pidarticulo" class="pidarticulo" type="hidden">{{ $producto->nombre }}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="number" name="pcantidad" class="pcantidad form-control" placeholder="Unidad">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="number" name="pprecio_venta" class="pprecio_venta form-control" step="0.01" min="0" value="{{ $producto->precio_venta }}" readonly>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success bt_add" id="bt_add" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" 
                                                                data-product-id="{{ $producto->IDproductos }}"
                                                                data-product-name="{{ $producto->nombre }}"
                                                                data-product-price="{{ $producto->precio_venta }}">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Información del Cliente</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('ventas.store') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="{{ route('ventas.store') }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <!-- ... Tu formulario para la información del cliente aquí ... -->
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>Nombre:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>Apellido Paterno:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="apellido_paterno" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>Apellido Materno:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="apellido_materno" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>Telefono:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label>CI:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="ci" class="form-control" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <label for="numero_ticket">N° Ticket</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="numero_ticket" readonly class="form-control" value="{{ $numeroTicket }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Detalles de la Venta</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('ventas.store') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
                                <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped mt-2">
                                    <thead style="background-color: #6777ef">
                                        <th style="color:#fff; width: 10%;">Opciones</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff; width: 30%;">Productos</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff; width: 10%;">Cantidad</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff; width: 30%;">Precio venta</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff; width: 20%;">Subtotal</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>
                                            <h4 id="total">0.00</h4>
                                            <input type="hidden" name='total_venta' id="total_venta">
                                        </th>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- Datos de la tabla aquí -->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                <a href="{{ route('ventas.index') }}" class="btn btn-info">
                                    <i class="fas fa-undo-alt"></i> Regresar
                                </a>
                                <input name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="hidden">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-dolly"></i> Guardar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @push('scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var detallesTable = document.getElementById('detalles');
            var totalElement = document.getElementById('total');
            var totalVentaInput = document.getElementById('total_venta');
            var productosTable = document.getElementById('productos-table');
    
            productosTable.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                var boton = event.target.closest('.bt_add');
                if (boton) {
                    agregarProductoADetalles(boton.closest('tr'));
                }
            });
    
            function agregarProductoADetalles(filaProducto) {
                var idProducto = filaProducto.querySelector('.pidarticulo').value;
                var nombreProducto = filaProducto.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerText;
                var cantidadInput = filaProducto.querySelector('.pcantidad');
                var cantidad = parseFloat(cantidadInput.value);
    
                if (!isNaN(cantidad) && cantidad > 0) {
                    var precio = parseFloat(filaProducto.querySelector('.pprecio_venta').value);
    
                    if (!isNaN(precio) && precio >= 0) {
                        var subtotal = cantidad * precio;
    
                        var nuevaFila = detallesTable.insertRow();
                        nuevaFila.innerHTML = `
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminarProducto(this)">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>${nombreProducto}</td>
                            <td>${cantidad}</td>
                            <td>${precio}</td>
                            <td>${subtotal.toFixed(2)}</td>
                        `;
    
                        cantidadInput.value = '';
                        actualizarTotal();
                    } else {
                        alert('El precio del producto no es válido.');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Ingresa una cantidad válida.');
                }
            }
    
            window.eliminarProducto = function (botonEliminar) {
                var filaDetalle = botonEliminar.closest('tr');
                detallesTable.deleteRow(filaDetalle.rowIndex);
                actualizarTotal();
            };
    
            function actualizarTotal() {
                var total = 0;
                var filasDetalles = detallesTable.rows;
    
                for (var i = 1; i < filasDetalles.length; i++) {
                    var subtotal = parseFloat(filasDetalles[i].cells[4].innerText) || 0;
                    total += isNaN(subtotal) ? 0 : subtotal;
                }
    
                totalElement.innerText = 'Bs. ' + total.toFixed(2);
                totalVentaInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
            var productosTable = document.getElementById('productos-table');
    
            searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
                var searchText = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
    
                for (var i = 1; i < productosTable.rows.length; i++) {
                    var productName = productosTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerText.toLowerCase();
                    var isVisible = productName.includes(searchText);
    
                    productosTable.rows[i].style.display = isVisible ? '' : 'none';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    @endpush

@endsection
```

this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\VentasFormRequest;
use App\Models\Clientes;
use App\Models\DetalleVentas;
use App\Models\Productos;
use App\Models\Promociones;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Ventas;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Response;




class VentasController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('permission:ver-ventas|crear-ventas|editar-ventas|detalle-ventas|borrar-ventas', ['only'=>['index']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:crear-ventas', ['only'=>['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:editar-ventas', ['only'=>['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:detalle-ventas', ['only' => ['show']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:borrar-ventas', ['only'=>['destroy']]);
        
       
     
    }
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('texto', ''); 

    $ventas = Ventas::join('clientes as c', 'ventas.IDclientes', '=', 'c.IDclientes')
        ->join('users as u', 'ventas.IDusuarios', '=', 'u.id')
        ->leftJoin('detalleventas as dv', 'ventas.IDventas', '=', 'dv.IDventas') 
        ->select(
            'ventas.IDventas',
            'c.nombre',
            'c.apellido_paterno',
            'c.apellido_materno',
            'u.name',
            'u.ap_paterno as usuario_ap_paterno',
            'u.ap_materno as usuario_ap_materno',
            'ventas.numero_ticket',
            'ventas.fecha_venta',
            'ventas.estado',
            'ventas.total'
        )
        ->where('ventas.numero_ticket', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->groupBy(
            'ventas.IDventas',
            'ventas.fecha_venta',
            'c.nombre',
            'c.apellido_paterno',
            'c.apellido_materno',
            'u.name',
            'usuario_ap_paterno',
            'usuario_ap_materno',
            'ventas.numero_ticket',
            'ventas.estado'
        )
        ->orderBy('ventas.IDventas', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('ventas.index', ["ventas" => $ventas, "texto" => $query]);
}


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
{
    
    $clientes = Clientes::all();
    $usuarios = User::all();

    $productos = Productos::where('inventario', '>', 0)->where('estado', 1)->get();
    
    $fechaActual = now(); // Obtiene la fecha actual
    $promociones = Promociones::where('fecha_inicio_promo', '<=', $fechaActual)
        ->where('fecha_fin_promo', '>=', $fechaActual)
        ->get();
   
    $venta = new Ventas();
    $numeroTicket = $venta->getNextTicketNumber();

    return view('ventas.agregar', [
        'clientes' => $clientes,
        'usuarios' => $usuarios,
        'productos' => $productos,
        'promociones' => $promociones,
        'numeroTicket' => $numeroTicket
    ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $mytime = Carbon::now('America/La_Paz');
    
            $cliente = Clientes::where('ci', $request->get('ci'))->first();
    
            if (!$cliente) {
                $cliente = new Clientes();
                $cliente->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
                $cliente->apellido_paterno = $request->get('apellido_paterno');
                $cliente->apellido_materno = $request->get('apellido_materno');
                $cliente->telefono = $request->get('telefono');
                $cliente->ci = $request->get('ci');
                $cliente->fecha_registro = $mytime->toDate();
                $cliente->estado = 1;
    
                $cliente->save(); 
            }
    
            $venta = new Ventas;
            $venta->IDclientes = $cliente->IDclientes;
            $venta->IDusuarios = Auth::user()->id;
            $venta->numero_ticket = $request->get('numero_ticket');
            $venta->fecha_venta = $mytime->toDate();
            $venta->estado = 1;
            $venta->total = $request->get('total_venta');
            $venta->save();
    
            // Detalles de la venta
            $IDproductos = $request->get('idProducto');
            $cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');
            $precio_venta = $request->get('precio');
    
            $cont = 0;
    
            while ($cont < count($IDproductos)) {
                $detalle = new DetalleVentas();
                $detalle->IDventas = $venta->IDventas; 
                $detalle->IDproductos = $IDproductos[$cont];
                $detalle->cantidad = $cantidad[$cont];
                $detalle->precio_venta = $precio_venta[$cont];
                $detalle->save();
                $cont = $cont + 1;            
            }   
    
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return redirect()->route('ventas.index')->with('error', 'Error en la transacción: ' . $th->getMessage());
        }
    
        return redirect()->route('ventas.index')->with('success', 'Venta guardada correctamente.');
    }
    
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show( $IDventas)
    {
        $venta = DB::table('ventas as v')
            ->join('clientes as c', 'c.IDclientes', '=', 'v.IDclientes')
            ->join('users as u', 'v.IDusuarios', '=', 'u.id')
            ->join('detalleventas as dv', 'dv.IDventas', '=', 'v.IDventas')
            ->select('v.IDventas','v.fecha_venta', 'c.nombre as cliente_nombre', 'c.apellido_paterno as cliente_ap_paterno', 'c.apellido_materno as cliente_ap_materno', 'u.name as usuario_nombre', 'u.ap_paterno as usuario_ap_paterno','u.ap_materno as usuario_ap_materno', 'v.numero_ticket', 'v.estado', 'v.total')
            ->where('v.IDventas', '=', $IDventas)
            ->first();



        $detalles = DB::table('detalleventas as d')
            ->join('productos as p', 'd.IDproductos', '=', 'p.IDproductos')
            ->join('promociones as pro','d.IDpromociones', '=', 'pro.IDpromociones')
            ->select('p.nombre as producto', 'd.cantidad', 'd.precio_venta', 'pro.nombre as promocion','pro.precio_venta as precio_promo')
            ->where('d.IDventas', '=', $IDventas)
            ->get();

        return view('ventas.detalles', ["venta" => $venta, "detalles" => $detalles]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Ventas $ventas)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Ventas $ventas)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy($IDventas)
    {
        $ventas = Ventas::find($IDventas);

        if (!$ventas) {
            return redirect()->route('ventas.index')->with('error', 'Venta no encontrado.');
        }

        // Cambiar el valor de estado
        $ventas->estado = ($ventas->estado == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        $ventas->save();

        return redirect()->route('ventas.index')->with('success', 'Estado del ingreso cambiado correctamente.');
    }
}
```

What happens is that it doesn't appear in the database but it doesn't show me any errors either.